# Kinect for Windows v2 hand cursor outside WPF windows

Tags: c#, .net, kinect, kinect-interaction

I would like to write an application where you can use your hand instead of mouse. I wrote some WPF and use a hand style and it work good.
But I want to use this control outside and WPF window, just like normal mouse coursor. Is it possible to write it with Kinect For Windows V2 ?

Comment: This type of thing already exists I suggest searching the internet.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't find any information about this.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a service, but not WPF app. So that it still can process input from Kinect in background, not only when your app is active and foreground.

You need to emit mouse move/click events in order to use it globally in the whole Windows OS. Here is one of examples on MSDN: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1ea09f18-94f6-4f4f-bcba-d02da27beaa4/control-mouse-position-and-generate-click-from-program-c-winforms-aim-control-pc-from-serial?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: But can't I build a WPF app and it will be working in background ?

Comment: Now I found that K4W v2 is not supported a service.

Comment: You can still use your WPF application, as long as it captures Kinect events while being minimized or invisible.